# Varied results for window.open

Tags: javascript, xul

I am working on a standalone XUL application and have this bit for opening a dialog window:

```
window.open("./help.xul","help","chrome,dialog,centerscreen,modal,resizable=no,close=no");
```

On Windows 7/8 this works as expected.  The dialog opens modal without any of the title bar buttons, cannot be resized and is centered on the parent.  However, on Linux (tested on Fedora & Ubuntu), all but the centerscreen features are ignored.

I've also tried it using

```
window.openDialog("./help.xul","help","chrome,centerscreen,modal,resizable=no,close=no");
```

with the same results.

I'm hoping a second (third, fourth, ad infinitum) set of eyes can tell me what may be going on to cause the varied result.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I ensured the version of XULRunner was the latest on Windows and Linux (v39.0).  Same results.

Comment: Look at which are the supported specs here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp. Not all of them are official supported in all the browsers.

Comment: It isn't a difference in browser issue as this is a standalone app using XUL.  

I did think it was maybe due to a difference in XULRunner.  But after changing to the latest version for both Windows and Linux, the results were the same.